# Magento CMS Page/Static Blocks - How to display store name?

Tags: variables, magento, static, content-management-system, block

I have number of Magento CMS pages and static blocks which use the variable {{store url=""}} to display the store url address in some text depending which store is being viewed.

I would like to also display the store name. Is there an equivalent which would display the store name, something like {{store name=""}}? *({{store name=""}} doesn't work btw)*

I don't have access to the .php files so would like to know if this is possible without access. If not, then I can request changes to the .php, I just need to know what to request.

Answer (score 2):

you can use any method on store object:

```
{{var store.getFrontendName()}}
```

search your codebase for further reference:

```
grep '{{store' app/locale/ -rsn
```

Comment: Thanks for an answer Anton but I'm not sure I understand it. I added this text to the CMS page "Welcome to {{var store.getFrontendName()}}" but when I look at the page on the website I see exactly the same. The {{var store.getFrontendName()}} is not replaced with the store name. The grep bit I don't understand.

Answer (score 1):

Try `{{config path="general/store_information/name"}}`.

Comment: Thank you Zyava. I added this text to the static block "Welcome to {{config path="general/store_information/name"}}" but when I view the webpage I see {{config path="general/store_information/name"}} instead of the store name.

Comment: Hmm, which magento version do you have? Works for me in CE 1.6.1.0-beta1

Comment: This works, but not in the WYSIWYG editor. So click the show/hide-editor button and then paste this code into the HTML. Then save it, and Magento will handle it. Afterwards you'll see this code in the WYSIWYG editor, but apparently the editor escapes this code somehow.